# How to make computer interface with circuit

Tags: script

I understand that I can build a circuit that will do whatever I like (ex: a simple circuit that will turn on a motor to open the blinds or something), and I can write a program that will automate my computer/mac however I like (ex: open this program at this time, or with this input and create a new file, ect).

My question is, how can I interface the two?  Is there an easy DIY or cheap commercial (or not cheap but functional) USB plug that will turn on/off from computer commands?  I'm basically looking for some sort of on/off switch I can script/applescript.  How would you even approach this problem, would I have to write my own driver some where along the way?

Comment: I remember reading something about a kit you could buy that would let you control electric switches, relays, electric-engines and such with your computer. It was specially made for home tinkerer and I remember thinking how much fun it looked.  Unfortunately my google-fu is failing me and I can't find a link for you.

Comment: Usually for this kind of thing you have to do a fair bit of tinkering, though there may be kits available. If you search for "home automation", you'll probably find pertinent information (there have been at least a few other similar questions on this site).

Comment: A little electronic engineering knowledge would be a good thing to have, here, also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used hardware from [phidgets.com](http://www.phidgets.com/). Attached a stepper motor with a stepper controller and used their drivers/api and it worked fine for my needs.

Looks like one of their [relays](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=9&product_id=1014) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Their relay looks higher voltage than I'd start with, but this is a great start, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at Arduino:  http://www.arduino.cc/

It provides a very flexible interface (hardware and software) between your computer and external circuitry.